# Am I writing Vim modelines incorrectly?

Tags: vim

I've appended the following Vim modeline to the end of a .md file:

```
# vim: ts=4:sw=4:softtabstop=4:expandtab:autoindent
```

I've also tried this:

```
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab autoindent:
```

However, if I check a setting like this for either case, I see that the tabstop is still set to 2:

```
:set ts?    " returns 2
```

Will Vim give greater precedence to any settings in my .vimrc or to ftplugin/markdown.vim?  I would think that a modeline inside a file would have the greatest precedence.

Comment: Modelines do overwrite your `.vimrc` or other configuration options normally (I used `# vim: set ts=2 sw=2 et :`, it worked as I expected). It's possible you're applying autocommands after the modeline changes have occurred. Is ts set correctly when you open the file with `vim -u NONE myfile.md`?

Comment: When I ran that command, tabstop was set to 8!  However, when I re-typed the modeline like yours (except I used 4 instead of 2), the settings correctly reflected these modeline settings.  I didn't see any 'autocmd' settings in my .vimrc that would affect these settings.

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to use the `set` keyword between `vim:` and `ts=4`?

Comment: @SanderVanhove, you don't need the `set` keyword. Modelines have a lot of options, see [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic)

Comment: Oh sorry, today I learned :)

Comment: @Ray, for example 1, is that the full content of the line, with no extra characters afterward? what is the output of `:verbose set modeline? modelines?` Are you root when editing these files? The first example works as written on my machine.

Comment: @SanderVanhove: There's two versions of modeline, one for when you need non-option text after the options (e.g. C-style comments), the other when you know the end of line is yours (e.g. bash-style comments). The former can't have `set`, the latter one must.